# Angular múltiplos ngif else passando parametro no template

Tags: angular

É possível fazer dois ngIf no angular.html? segue um exemplo

```
if(1=2){
}else{
    if(){
    }
}
```

preciso fazer duas verificações.

Verificar restrição do professor caso for false verificar disponibilidade da sala de aula.

se um exemplo do meu código. Sou novo em angular e não sei como tudo funciona.

```html
<td *ngIf="!restricaoSegUm; else templateName"
    *ngIf="!restricaoSalaSegUm; else sala"
    [dragula]='"another-bag"'
    [dragulaModel]='segUm'>
    <div [@resultadoAnimacao]="animationsState"
        class="cursor-pointer"
        *ngFor='let s1 of segUm'
        (dblclick)="removeNumbers(s1,this.segUm)">
        {{s1?.no_diciplinas}}
    </div>
</td>

<ng-template #templateName>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54);"></td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template-sala #sala>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(244, 146, 54);"></td>
</ng-template-sala>
```

Alguma ajuda de como resolver?

Answer (score -1):

Às vezes escrever em pseudocódigo ajuda a clarear o objetivo:

```
se restricaoSegUm == False && restricaoSalaSegUm == False então
    mostrar <div class="cursor-pointer">
senao
    se restricaoSegUm == True então
        mostrar <ng-template #templateName>
    senao se restricaoSalaSegUm == True então
        mostrar <ng-template-sala #sala>
```

Fazendo uso da diretiva [`NgIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) (Angular 4 e 5)

```html
<td *ngIf="!restricaoSegUm && !restricaoSalaSegUm"
    [dragula]='"another-bag"'
    [dragulaModel]='segUm'>
    <div [@resultadoAnimacao]="animationsState"
        class="cursor-pointer"
        *ngFor='let s1 of segUm'
        (dblclick)="removeNumbers(s1,this.segUm)">
        {{s1?.no_diciplinas}}
    </div>
</td>

<ng-template *ngIf="restricaoSegUm; else sala" #templateName>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(244, 67, 54);"></td>
</ng-template>

<ng-template-sala *ngIf="restricaoSalaSegUm" #sala>
    <td style="background-color: rgb(244, 146, 54);"></td>
</ng-template-sala>
```

Comment: Amigo, tem como o ng-template receber uma variavel? unica coisa que preciso fazer é: caso a restrição for de professor ng-tamplate fica com background-color vermelha caso for de sala ng-template fica laranja

Comment: @Herick não seria o caso portanto de usar `ng-class` na div `cursor-pointer`? Acredito que você queira estilizar a div que obtêm informações ao invés de um `ng-template` vazio.